# Windows Domain User with Admin privileges cannot access a drive with full permissions in psql

Tags: postgresql, permissions, windows, psql

I have installed the standard PostgreSQL 9.5 from Enterprise DB with a domain-level *postgres* user who has domain-level admin group membership. I have explicitly added full permissions for this user to the D: drive of my Windows Server 2012 machine and explicitly granted full permissions on several root and subfolders on the same drive.

However, no matter what I try, I cannot get the command line version of *psql* to recognize any permissions for this user. And it seems to be exclusively about the *psql* command environment.

For example, this fails:

```
\o 'd:/database/tiger'
```

with

> permissions denied

even though I am logged in as the *postgres* domain admin user who owns the database and whose account is the service account for PostgreSQL.

If I simply type *psql* into a command prompt (either with or without selecting *Run as administrator*), I am prompted for a password, but the correct password for the domain *postgres* account is not recognized.

Is it possible that the PostgreSQL installation created a 'local' *postgres* account (and that is the one *psql* is expecting or running under)?

I can find no local accounts on the machine at all and all access to the local accounts admin tools is denied.

*psql* exhibits this behavior whether I start it from a normal windows command line dialog, or from the pgAdmin3 *Plugins* menu item.

Who is this guy that *psql* is expecting?

Comment: Try creating  a user who is not Admin on the machine in question. IIRC (form Linux) that PostgreSQL doesn't like root users accessing the database and/or installing - can't recall exactly, it's a long time since I tried, but you should be able to set up a non-Windows admin user as the admin user on the PostgreSQL server.